# Installshield 2009 installer refuses to onfigure for a second user (did work until recently)

Tags: windows-xp, installshield-2009

Since years we use installshield to deliver our software. Since the last Version of our software the following happens:

After installing the program for "all users", when a restricted user logs in, he sees our applications Icon on the desktop. When double clicking it the first time a dialog appears "Configuring ". In recent versions after a while the dialog disappeared and our program stared. Now the process is aborted with a message: "The function is hosted on a unavailable network resource". Our program does not start. But when we create a shortcut to the .exe file by hand everything's fine.

We did not make any modifications to the installer project recently (besides changing the Version number). We also denied to install updates.

Questions:

- What can the problem be?
- How can i debug a installer?

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure about Installshield (I use Wise) but you should check the following:

1. Set the MSI Property "ALLUSERS" to 1 in the "Property" table of the MSI database.  See Windows Installer SDK documentation for more details.  This ensures that all users get a shortcut for launching the application.
2. Call your installer with 
   MSIEXEC.EXE **/v** MyInstall.MSI

from the command line (this sets the logging to verbose) - might help!

Liam

Comment: How can i run msiexec.exe with a setup.exe. It refuses to to with the parameters you wrote.

Comment: The setup.exe is usually used to bootstrap the prerequisite components of an install.  Do you have the option in Installshield to output the main setup as msi or several separate files?